# Simple OOP: Python, saving object names via __init__ v2

Tags: python, oop

OK, I asked a similar question before but was too confusing because of my lack of correct terminology.  This is my second bite at the apple.

I want to create an object whose `__init__` will save the name assigned to the object in a list.

kinda like this:

```
class Object():

  def __init__(self, something):

    self.something = something
    (now how do I save the xxx, xx, and x names I create below?)

xxx = Object(something)

xx = Object(something)

x = Object(something)
```

I want a global `total_objects` (or whatever) that contains `[xxx, xx, x]`
Sorry for the crummy formatting.  I hope my question is still clear.

such as:

```
 total_objects = [xxx, xx, x]
```

Also, please let me know if my approach is sloppy and there's a better way, but I don't want to have to save the 'x' names in the code itself. Such as `total_objects.append(xxx)`  `total_objects.append(xx)` etc.  I want it to be automatic.

Comment: Do you want the name of the object or the instance of the object?

Comment: This exact question was on SO some time ago, it was even answered (with some dirty hack), but I'm afraid can't find it. My idea is: write this explicitly or use Lisp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lis = []
class Object():
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.something = var 
        lis.append(self)  #here self is the reference to the instance being created and you can save it in a list to access it later
xxx = Object('123')
xx = Object('12')
x = Object('1')

for x in lis:
    print(x.something)
```

**output:**

```
123
12
1
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do exactly this in Python, because there's nothing requiring an object to be assigned to a specific name, so the initializer doesn't get passed such info.

For instance, the following lines are all valid Python:

```
x = Object()
y = x
Object()
[Object() for i in xrange(5)]
x = [Object() for i in xrange(5)]
```

If you want to keep track of the instances of the object, you can do that, but that's separate from the names that reference those instances:

```
class Object(object):
    my_instances = []

    def __init__(self):
        my_instances.append(self)
```

Then `Object.my_instances` would contain a list of the instances:

```
[<__main__.Object instance at 0x012BA760>, ...]
```

However this may not be what you want.